# MS Access - Main menu form with 2 text boxes used to open and filter a different form - getting a type mismatch (Run error 13)

Tags: sql, vba, forms, ms-access, filter

I have a main menu where users type in a name of a station (text box) and the name of a cohort (text box) and it would open a new form based on these values.  For example, if "New York" was entered for a station and "1b" was entered for cohort, then the form would filter to only show data that have both. However, I am getting a data mismatch error.

The fields text boxed at my main menu are called "detailed_s_station" and "detailed_s_cohort". The names of the respective fields in the form I want to filter these values are called "station" and "cohort".

I can get this to work if there are only one set of criteria (e.g., if I just search for the cohort or just search for the station), however something is going on with my AND here.  Any help is appreciated to help me get rid of this data mismatch error.

```
Private Sub Command41_Click()

Dim stDocName22 As String
Dim stLinkCriteria22 As String
stDocName22 = "frm_scans"
stLinkCriteria22 = "[station] ='" & Me![detailed_s_station] & "'" And "[cohort] ='" & Me![detailed_s_cohort] & "'"
DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName22, , , stLinkCriteria22, acFormEdit, acWindowNormal

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are having is how you are joining the string together. Instead try:

```
Private Sub Command41_Click()

Dim stDocName22 As String
Dim stLinkCriteria22 As String
stDocName22 = "frm_scans"
stLinkCriteria22 = "[station] ='" & Me![detailed_s_station] & "' And [cohort] ='" & Me![detailed_s_cohort] & "'"
DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName22, , , stLinkCriteria22, acFormEdit, acWindowNormal

End Sub
```

If you ever have problems like this in future, a quick `Debug.Print strLinkCriteria22` would show you the contents of the string that is causing problems.

Regards,

Comment: Wow, I got two things out of this one.  Thank you for the debugging tip as well.  I appreciate it.